# Theorem 3.4, Rudin Functional analysis.

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

i'm studying this Theorem 3.4, Rudin's Functional Anlysis, page 59, buy i'm a little bit stuck in some parts of the proof.

The Theorem says:
Suppose $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, non empty, convex sets in a topological vector space $X$.

a) if $A$ is open there exist $\Lambda \in X^{*}$ and $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\Re (\Lambda x) < \gamma \leq \Re (\Lambda y),$$
for every $x\in A$ and for every $y \in B$.

But i don't understand how to use that $A$ is an open set, i mean in the proof says that $f(A)$ is open because $f$ is an open map, but i don't get at all why this is too important, i will really appreciate any hint.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking why it matters that $A$ is open?  If that's the case, just consider $A=(0,1]$ and $B=(1,2)$ as subsets of $X=\mathbb{R}$.  Then no such functional exists.

Comment: Yes, that's the question, but i don't understand how to use it in the proof, i mean maybe i'm assuming something wrong

Comment: If $A$ is open then $A-B-\{x_0\}$ is a convex neighbourhood of $0$. Then generate $p$ using the Justin Bieber functional of this set.

Comment: @copper.hat What is the Justin Bieber functional?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven it is a modern pop star version of the Minkowski functional.

Comment: @copper.hat Ok ^^ then how would you characterize Minkowski? Rock star?

Comment: Up until the last step, you just need $C = A - B + x_0$ to be a convex neighborhood of $0$.  For instance, this would be true if $B$ is open.  In the last step, however, you use the fact that $\sup \Lambda(A) \not\in \Lambda(A)$, which requires an additional property of $A$.  One such property is that $A$ is open (which is nice since now you only need to assume $B$ is convex and disjoint from $A$)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Relativitely speaking, yes, a true space time rock star.

Comment: so, the importance that $A$ is an open set, it's to guarantee that i can define the Minkowski functional (o Justin Bieber functional, just kidding) in an absorbent set $C$, exactly as Minkowski functional is defined,  am i right? but i have one more question, just in order to be sure, i use the fact that $f(A)$ is open to guarantee that there is a number $\gamma = \sup \Lambda (A)$, such that $\Lambda(x)<\gamma\leq \Lambda(y)$